# NGINX Reverse Proxy throws HTTP 503 on JIRA

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, jira

I'm setting up a internal server for JIRA, Jenkins etc. For simplification i use an Reverse Proxy and docker-compose.

My **docker-compose.yml** has following configuration:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  proxy:
    container_name: proxy
    image: nginx:alpine
    init: true
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    networks:
      proxynet:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.2
    depends_on:
      - jenkins
      - nexus
    volumes:
      - ./reverse-proxy/data/app.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./reverse-proxy/logs:/var/logs/nginx/
  ...
  jira:
    container_name: jira
    image: cptactionhank/atlassian-jira:latest
    init: true
    restart: unless-stopped
    networks:
      proxynet:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.5
    volumes:
      - ./jira/webapp:/var/atlassian/jira
      - ./jira/logs:/opt/atlassian/jira/logs
    environment:
      - X_PROXY_PORT=8080
      - X_PROXY_SCHEME="http"

volumes:
  data:

networks:
  proxynet:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.0.0/16
```

reverse-proxy/data/**app.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 192.123.456.789;

    ...

    location /jira {
        proxy_set_header    Host $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_pass          http://172.20.0.5:8080/jira;
        proxy_ssl_verify    off;
        proxy_read_timeout  90;
    }

}
```

If i visit the 192.123.456.789/jira, i get an HTTP ERROR 503.

NGINX access log:

```
[04/Sep/2019:16:49:33 +0000] "GET /jira HTTP/1.1" 503 36 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

JIRA startup log:

```
                  `sMMMMMMMMMMMMMM+
                     MMMMMMMMMMMMMM
                     :sdMMMMMMMMMMM
                             MMMMMM
          `sMMMMMMMMMMMMMM+  MMMMMM
             MMMMMMMMMMMMMM  +MMMMM
              :sMMMMMMMMMMM   MMMMM
                     MMMMMM    `UOJ
   `sMMMMMMMMMMMMM+  MMMMMM
     MMMMMMMMMMMMMM  +MMMMM
      :sdMMMMMMMMMM   MMMMM
             MMMMMM    `UOJ
             MMMMMM
             +MMMMM
              MMMMM
               `UOJ

      Atlassian Jira
      Version : 8.3.3


If you encounter issues starting or stopping JIRA, please see the Troubleshooting guide at https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/jadm-docs-083/Troubleshooting+installation

Using JIRA_HOME:       /var/atlassian/jira

Server startup logs are located in /opt/atlassian/jira/logs/catalina.out
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.136 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.40
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.141 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Apr 10 2019 14:31:19 UTC
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.142 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.5.40.0
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.142 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Linux
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.142 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            4.15.0-54-generic
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.143 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.143 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.144 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_212-b04
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.144 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            IcedTea
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.144 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         /opt/atlassian/jira
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.145 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         /opt/atlassian/jira
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.146 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/atlassian/jira/conf/logging.properties
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.147 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.147 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xms384m
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.148 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xmx2048m
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.148 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:InitialCodeCacheSize=32m
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.148 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.149 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.awt.headless=true
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.149 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Datlassian.standalone=JIRA
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.153 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.jasper.runtime.BodyContentImpl.LIMIT_BUFFER=true
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.154 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dmail.mime.decodeparameters=true
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.154 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.dom4j.factory=com.atlassian.core.xml.InterningDocumentFactory
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.155 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.155 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.155 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djira.home=/var/atlassian/jira
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.156 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Datlassian.plugins.startup.options=-fg
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.156 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.156 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.157 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.157 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Xloggc:/opt/atlassian/jira/logs/atlassian-jira-gc-%t.log
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.158 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.158 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.158 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:GCLogFileSize=20M
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.159 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:+PrintGCDetails
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.159 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.160 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.160 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -XX:+PrintGCCause
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.161 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.161 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=/opt/atlassian/jira
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.163 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=/opt/atlassian/jira
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.163 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/atlassian/jira/temp
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.164 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.505 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.555 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 1377 ms
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.576 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
04-Sep-2019 17:03:57.578 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.40
2019-09-04 17:04:05,574 localhost-startStop-1 INFO      [c.a.jira.startup.JiraHomeStartupCheck] The jira.home directory '/var/atlassian/jira' is validated and locked for exclusive use by this instance.
2019-09-04 17:04:05,783 JIRA-Bootstrap INFO      [c.a.jira.startup.JiraStartupLogger]

    ****************
    JIRA starting...
    ****************

2019-09-04 17:04:05,923 JIRA-Bootstrap INFO      [c.a.jira.startup.JiraStartupLogger]

    ___ Environment _____________________________

         JIRA Build                                    : 8.3.3#803004-sha1:4d4040e0714d65b7fffa4801569d014c0b16eaa9
         Build Date                                    : Wed Aug 28 00:00:00 GMT 2019
         JIRA Installation Type                        : Standalone
         Application Server                            : Apache Tomcat/8.5.40 - Servlet API 3.1
         Java Version                                  : 1.8.0_212 - IcedTea
         Current Working Directory                     : /var/atlassian/jira
         Maximum Allowable Memory                      : 1979MB
         Total Memory                                  : 371MB
         Free Memory                                   : 330MB
         Used Memory                                   : 41MB
         Memory Pool: Code Cache                       : Code Cache: init = 33554432(32768K) used = 8746176(8541K) committed = 33554432(32768K) max = 536870912(524288K)
         Memory Pool: Metaspace                        : Metaspace: init = 0(0K) used = 21664984(21157K) committed = 22331392(21808K) max = -1(-1K)
         Memory Pool: Compressed Class Space           : Compressed Class Space: init = 0(0K) used = 2323808(2269K) committed = 2490368(2432K) max = 1073741824(1048576K)
         Memory Pool: Eden Space                       : Eden Space: init = 107479040(104960K) used = 22147168(21628K) committed = 107544576(105024K) max = 572653568(559232K)
         Memory Pool: Survivor Space                   : Survivor Space: init = 13369344(13056K) used = 0(0K) committed = 13369344(13056K) max = 71565312(69888K)
         Memory Pool: Tenured Gen                      : Tenured Gen: init = 268435456(262144K) used = 21798312(21287K) committed = 268435456(262144K) max = 1431699456(1398144K)
         JVM Input Arguments                           : -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/opt/atlassian/jira/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Xms384m -Xmx2048m -XX:InitialCodeCacheSize=32m -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m -Djava.awt.headless=true -Datlassian.standalone=JIRA -Dorg.apache.jasper.runtime.BodyContentImpl.LIMIT_BUFFER=true -Dmail.mime.decodeparameters=true -Dorg.dom4j.factory=com.atlassian.core.xml.InterningDocumentFactory -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -Djava.locale.providers=COMPAT -Djira.home=/var/atlassian/jira -Datlassian.plugins.startup.options=-fg -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027 -Xloggc:/opt/atlassian/jira/logs/atlassian-jira-gc-%t.log -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=20M -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintGCCause -Dignore.endorsed.dirs= -Dcatalina.base=/opt/atlassian/jira -Dcatalina.home=/opt/atlassian/jira -Djava.io.tmpdir=/opt/atlassian/jira/temp
         Java Compatibility Information                : JIRA version = 8.3.3, Java Version = 1.8.0_212

    ___ Java System Properties _________________

         atlassian.plugins.startup.options             : -fg
         atlassian.standalone                          : JIRA
         awt.toolkit                                   : sun.awt.X11.XToolkit
         catalina.base                                 : /opt/atlassian/jira
         catalina.home                                 : /opt/atlassian/jira
         catalina.useNaming                            : true
         common.loader                                 : "${catalina.base}/lib",
                                                         "${catalina.base}/lib/*.jar",
                                                         "${catalina.home}/lib",
                                                         "${catalina.home}/lib/*.jar"
         file.encoding                                 : UTF-8
         file.encoding.pkg                             : sun.io
         ignore.endorsed.dirs                          :
         java.awt.graphicsenv                          : sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment
         java.awt.headless                             : true
         java.awt.printerjob                           : sun.print.PSPrinterJob
         java.class.version                            : 52.0
         java.home                                     : /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre
         java.io.tmpdir                                : /opt/atlassian/jira/temp
         java.locale.providers                         : COMPAT
         java.naming.factory.initial                   : org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory
         java.naming.factory.url.pkgs                  : org.apache.naming
         java.protocol.handler.pkgs                    : org.apache.catalina.webresources
         java.runtime.name                             : OpenJDK Runtime Environment
         java.runtime.version                          : 1.8.0_212-b04
         java.specification.name                       : Java Platform API Specification
         java.specification.vendor                     : Oracle Corporation
         java.specification.version                    : 1.8
         java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.common.threadFactory : org.apache.catalina.startup.SafeForkJoinWorkerThreadFactory
         java.util.logging.config.file                 : /opt/atlassian/jira/conf/logging.properties
         java.util.logging.manager                     : org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
         java.vendor                                   : IcedTea
         java.vendor.url                               : https://icedtea.classpath.org
         java.vendor.url.bug                           : https://icedtea.classpath.org/bugzilla
         java.version                                  : 1.8.0_212
         java.vm.info                                  : mixed mode
         java.vm.name                                  : OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
         java.vm.specification.name                    : Java Virtual Machine Specification
         java.vm.specification.vendor                  : Oracle Corporation
         java.vm.specification.version                 : 1.8
         java.vm.vendor                                : IcedTea
         java.vm.version                               : 25.212-b04
         jdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize                    : 2048
         jira.home                                     : /var/atlassian/jira
         mail.mime.decodeparameters                    : true
         org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK : 0027
         org.apache.jasper.runtime.BodyContentImpl.LIMIT_BUFFER : true
         org.dom4j.factory                             : com.atlassian.core.xml.InterningDocumentFactory
         os.arch                                       : amd64
         os.name                                       : Linux
         os.version                                    : 4.15.0-54-generic
         package.access                                : sun.,
                                                         org.apache.catalina.,
                                                         org.apache.coyote.,
                                                         org.apache.jasper.,
                                                         org.apache.tomcat.
         package.definition                            : sun.,
                                                         java.,
                                                         org.apache.catalina.,
                                                         org.apache.coyote.,
                                                         org.apache.jasper.,
                                                         org.apache.naming.,
                                                         org.apache.tomcat.
         server.loader                                 :
         shared.loader                                 :
         sun.arch.data.model                           : 64
         sun.boot.library.path                         : /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64
         sun.cpu.endian                                : little
         sun.cpu.isalist                               :
         sun.io.unicode.encoding                       : UnicodeLittle
         sun.java.command                              : org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
         sun.java.launcher                             : SUN_STANDARD
         sun.jnu.encoding                              : UTF-8
         sun.management.compiler                       : HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
         sun.os.patch.level                            : unknown
         tomcat.util.buf.StringCache.byte.enabled      : true
         tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToScan : log4j-taglib*.jar,
                                                         log4j-web*.jar,
                                                         log4javascript*.jar,
                                                         slf4j-taglib*.jar
         tomcat.util.scan.StandardJarScanFilter.jarsToSkip : annotations-api.jar,
                                                         ant-junit*.jar,
                                                         ant-launcher.jar,
                                                         ant.jar,
                                                         asm-*.jar,
                                                         aspectj*.jar,
                                                         bootstrap.jar,
                                                         catalina-ant.jar,
                                                         catalina-ha.jar,
                                                         catalina-jmx-remote.jar,
                                                         catalina-storeconfig.jar,
                                                         catalina-tribes.jar,
                                                         catalina-ws.jar,
                                                         catalina.jar,
                                                         cglib-*.jar,
                                                         cobertura-*.jar,
                                                         commons-beanutils*.jar,
                                                         commons-codec*.jar,
                                                         commons-collections*.jar,
                                                         commons-daemon.jar,
                                                         commons-dbcp*.jar,
                                                         commons-digester*.jar,
                                                         commons-fileupload*.jar,
                                                         commons-httpclient*.jar,
                                                         commons-io*.jar,
                                                         commons-lang*.jar,
                                                         commons-logging*.jar,
                                                         commons-math*.jar,
                                                         commons-pool*.jar,
                                                         dom4j-*.jar,
                                                         easymock-*.jar,
                                                         ecj-*.jar,
                                                         el-api.jar,
                                                         geronimo-spec-jaxrpc*.jar,
                                                         h2*.jar,
                                                         hamcrest-*.jar,
                                                         hibernate*.jar,
                                                         httpclient*.jar,
                                                         icu4j-*.jar,
                                                         jasper-el.jar,
                                                         jasper.jar,
                                                         jaspic-api.jar,
                                                         jaxb-*.jar,
                                                         jaxen-*.jar,
                                                         jdom-*.jar,
                                                         jetty-*.jar,
                                                         jmx-tools.jar,
                                                         jmx.jar,
                                                         jsp-api.jar,
                                                         jstl.jar,
                                                         jta*.jar,
                                                         junit-*.jar,
                                                         junit.jar,
                                                         log4j*.jar,
                                                         mail*.jar,
                                                         objenesis-*.jar,
                                                         oraclepki.jar,
                                                         oro-*.jar,
                                                         servlet-api-*.jar,
                                                         servlet-api.jar,
                                                         slf4j*.jar,
                                                         taglibs-standard-spec-*.jar,
                                                         tagsoup-*.jar,
                                                         tomcat-api.jar,
                                                         tomcat-coyote.jar,
                                                         tomcat-dbcp.jar,
                                                         tomcat-i18n-*.jar,
                                                         tomcat-jdbc.jar,
                                                         tomcat-jni.jar,
                                                         tomcat-juli-adapters.jar,
                                                         tomcat-juli.jar,
                                                         tomcat-util-scan.jar,
                                                         tomcat-util.jar,
                                                         tomcat-websocket.jar,
                                                         tools.jar,
                                                         websocket-api.jar,
                                                         wsdl4j*.jar,
                                                         xercesImpl.jar,
                                                         xml-apis.jar,
                                                         xmlParserAPIs-*.jar,
                                                         xmlParserAPIs.jar,
                                                         xom-*.jar
         user.country                                  : US
         user.dir                                      : /var/atlassian/jira
         user.home                                     : /sbin
         user.language                                 : en
         user.name                                     : daemon
         user.timezone                                 : GMT

2019-09-04 17:04:06,338 JIRA-Bootstrap INFO      [c.a.j.config.database.SystemDatabaseConfigurationLoader] Reading database configuration from /var/atlassian/jira/dbconfig.xml
2019-09-04 17:04:06,391 JIRA-Bootstrap INFO      [c.a.j.config.database.SystemDatabaseConfigurationLoader] Reading database configuration from /var/atlassian/jira/dbconfig.xml
2019-09-04 17:04:06,392 JIRA-Bootstrap INFO      [c.a.j.config.database.SystemDatabaseConfigurationLoader] Reading database configuration from /var/atlassian/jira/dbconfig.xml
2019-09-04 17:04:08,155 JIRA-Bootstrap INFO      [c.a.j.config.database.SystemDatabaseConfigurationLoader] Reading database configuration from /var/atlassian/jira/dbconfig.xml
2019-09-04 17:04:08,187 JIRA-Bootstrap INFO      [c.a.jira.startup.JiraStartupLogger]

    ___ Starting the JIRA Plugin System _________________

2019-09-04 17:04:17,775 JIRA-Bootstrap INFO      [c.a.j.config.database.SystemDatabaseConfigurationLoader] Reading database configuration from /var/atlassian/jira/dbconfig.xml
2019-09-04 17:04:17,931 JIRA-Bootstrap INFO      [c.a.jira.startup.JiraStartupLogger] Running JIRA startup checks.
2019-09-04 17:04:17,933 JIRA-Bootstrap INFO      [c.a.jira.startup.JiraStartupLogger] JIRA pre-database startup checks completed successfully.
2019-09-04 17:04:18,023 JIRA-Bootstrap INFO      [c.a.j.config.database.DatabaseConfigurationManagerImpl] The database is not yet configured. Enqueuing Database Checklist Launcher on post-database-configured-but-pre-database-activated queue
2019-09-04 17:04:18,024 JIRA-Bootstrap INFO      [c.a.j.config.database.DatabaseConfigurationManagerImpl] The database is not yet configured. Enqueuing Post database-configuration launchers on post-database-activated queue
2019-09-04 17:04:18,045 JIRA-Bootstrap INFO      [c.a.jira.startup.LauncherContextListener] Memory Usage:
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      Heap memory     :  Used:   73 MiB.  Committed:  371 MiB.  Max: 1980 MiB
      Non-heap memory :  Used:   68 MiB.  Committed:   86 MiB.  Max: 1536 MiB
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      TOTAL           :  Used:  141 MiB.  Committed:  458 MiB.  Max: 3516 MiB
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
04-Sep-2019 17:05:03.590 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
04-Sep-2019 17:05:03.618 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
04-Sep-2019 17:05:03.701 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 66145 ms
```

I also started JIRA without the X_PROXY_* environment variables, but still no success.

I'm a bit confused because jira has started successfully, but nginx can't access it apparently. What am i missing?

Comment: Have you checked the connection between containers? Can you start the nginx container and run ping to jira? Can you open jira connecting directly? Are both containers in the same network? For me or seems the problem comes from networking

Comment: @mndrye I would say the connection between the containers work, because jenkins or nexus got the same netwok configuration in docker-compose like jira and they work properly. I can ping to 172.20.0.5 (jira), but when i do an curl on 172.20.0.5:8080, i get an empty response

Comment: did you try to link it using links ?

Comment: @MontassarBouagina not yet, but is this necessary? The other containers can also be reached without docker-compose links, im just asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think i have found your problem. In the nginx config you have this line

```
location /jira {

...
```

Change it to

```
location ^~ /jira {
    add_header Channel-id "JIRA";

...
```

Comment: COuld you connect to your nginx container y run a curl to the jira? Just to ensure that you got connectivity

Comment: Another idea it just came to mi mind is to run tcpdump on a container (jira or ngnix) and check for traffic between them

Comment: I got no response if i curl to jira in my nginx container. I think the problem comes from jira, because without nginx i can call jira without no problem. Probably there is a missing proxy config for jira, but nothing works..

Comment: Did you use curl directly to the jira?

Comment: Yes, in jira container: curl localhost:8080 -> empty response; in nginx container: curl localhost/jira -> empty response

Comment: And curl <jira_ip> from the container?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199042/discussion-between-mndrye-and-harvix).

Comment: Where you able to fix it?